# New to SQL, how do I use results from a SELECT call on TableA to SELECT against TableB?

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin to query the database.

I want to select all the entries in TableA where Date='2010-08-01'.  Then I want to use the SubID attributes of the items in the result table to find all the entries in TableB with matching SubIDs.  I know I have to use a JOIN somewhere, but I am not sure how or where.

I searched StackOverflow, and there appear to be a lot of similar questions, but none as basic (aka noob) as mine.  I couldn't really figure out what they were talking about.  To give you an idea of what I know, I started learning SQL today, and I read through the W3 School tutorial on SQL.  I feel like the answer will be extremely obvious and I will smack myself for not figuring it out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good reference is http://www.w3schools.com/sql

What you need is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b on a.SubID = b.SubID
WHERE a.Date = '2010-08-01'
```

---

Edit as per the other posts - a JOIN is likely to be more efficient, *however* if you have multiple records in TableB with the same `SubID`, you will get duplicate records from TableA returned.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a JOIN - just a subquery to filter TableB. Like so, for example:

```
SELECT SubID
FROM TableB
WHERE SubID IN
    (SELECT SubID
     FROM TableA
     WHERE Date='2010-08-01');
```

That said, you *can* use a join, as per @ck's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a join, [ck's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834568/new-to-sql-how-do-i-use-results-from-a-select-call-on-tablea-to-select-against-t/3834581#3834581) offers a simple solution.

Another way of approaching this would be to use a subquery (this came to my mind upon reading your question title):

```
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE SubID IN
    (SELECT SubID FROM TableA WHERE Date = '2010-08-01')
```

The outer `SELECT` query (selecting from `TableB`) chooses rows whose `SubID`s are found in the result set of the inner `SELECT` query (selecting from `TableA`). So for example if `TableA` turns up five rows with these `SubID`s:

- 8
- 11
- 12
- 27
- 35

Then rows will be selected from `TableB` whose `SubID`s are `IN (8, 11, 12, 27, 35)`.